# Android Application crashing on load. Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, debugging, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have created new Xamarin.Forms (Portable) application and just start debugging the application and I am getting below error.

```
Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

I don't know, Why I am getting this error or How to resolve this issue? Please check this Screenshot.

[image]

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Looks like you might be running into this bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=41380 Please ensure you have a proper theme applied to your `<application>`: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/android/appcompat/#4._Update_AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Hi @JonDouglas please check this screenshot, I think I haven't changed anything. http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2068376/8ebbafe33d8eb916873c521204cb33eb **I have created another new project and getting same error.

Comment: Can you post your Xamarin version information from Help -> About Visual Studio and post your Xamarin information? I wonder if this is a bug with the template in that version. I will have to investigate given I'm seeing the theme only applied to the Activity level.

Comment: Please check this screenshot: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2068412/de2e2d7cfa3026a3779b6f7fc4aa5e1f is there anything else you want from me?

Comment: Can you please try the `Beta` channel release to see if this template is fixed?

Comment: When you render a layout to android platform will get the issue. Can you show the android platform reference and. Xamarin portable `app.cs` code about `mainpage`.

Comment: @MikeMa I am just creating a Xamarin.Forms [Portable] new project and trying to debug, and I am getting above error.

Comment: Yes it could be an error, if you do not have the support v7 in the android project reference. Can you change the mainpage to content page and try again?

Comment: I am not sure about this, I have checked the reference of Support V7 and it is there. please check the screenshot: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2070658/46e2f7d349e318d7c2c7b557b177cf16
As per the @JonDouglas 's comment, I have updated the `beta` channel and it's installing now, I will try to create a new project now.

Comment: @JonDouglas I have updated Xamarin to Beta channel and tried to create a new project and I got the same error.

Comment: Hi @JonDouglas is there any solution for this problem. I really can't work on the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

- Manually remove each of the NuGet package one by one in the Android
  project only. You may have to do multiple passes of removing them due
  to dependency.
- Restart VS
- Then just add Xamarin.Forms package only. All the necessary packages
  will be added automatically.
- Clean and rebuild the project.

> I don't guarantee that it will definitely work. But it is one of the
>   possible solutions.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem happened to me and i tried the all solutions on the internet but it did not fixed.

Then i updated xamarin.forms nuget to version 2.3.3.180 and it worked

Comment: I am using the same `Xamarin.Forms.2.3.3.180`